# PHP MySQL query with parameters returns sytax error because of the parameters

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code in php:

```
$id=1;
    $query = 'select id from role_perm where perm_id = :id';
    if($statement =$GLOBALS["DB"]->prepare($query)){
    $result =& $statement->execute(array(':id' => $id));
    $t = $result->fetch_all();
```

But when I try to ran this code i get an error:

> 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ':id' at line 1

I looked through a lot of questions and info on internet trying to put my statements in different ways, but I always end up with error like this, I tried ? for parameters too. How can I make it recognize parameters?
My database config:

```
$databaseConnection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if ($databaseConnection->connect_error)
{
    die("Database selection failed: " . $databaseConnection->connect_error);
}
// Create tables if needed.
prep_DB_content();
$GLOBALS['DB'] = $databaseConnection ;
```

Comment: What is `$GLOBALS["DB"]`? In other words: what database driver do you use? My guess is you are trying to use `PDO` syntax with the `mysql` or the `mysqli` driver.

Comment: Take a look at the PDO documentation page at Example #2 (if you're using PDO) - 
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: @arkascha ok i updated.  I am using mysqli, you are right! what should I change then?

Comment: I suggest you take a look into the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = 'select id from role_perm where perm_id = ?';
if($statement = $GLOBALS["DB"]->prepare($query)){
   $statement->bind_param("i", $id);
   $statement->execute();
   $statement->store_result();
   $statement->bind_result($id_result);
   while ($statement->fetch()) {
       // code here
   }
   $statement->close();
}
```

Comment: $id_result is undefined, where i should get it from?

Comment: will there only be one result from the query? If so i'll change my answer

Comment: it suppose to be an array of results.

Comment: your are unable to receive an array of results when your are using prepared statements. instead the variable $id_result contains the id from the query and you can only use that variable inside the while loop. The while loop runs once for each row that is a result from the query.

Comment: add `echo $statement->num_rows;` after execute(); and tell me what it says

Comment: it is 0. but query itself is correct, when i run it in mysql it returns 2 rows..this is strange

Comment: just remembered you need to put `$statement->store_result();` before the num_rows try it again

Comment: yeah, now it returns 2, as it suppose to.

Comment: so if you put `echo $id_result;` inside the while loop does it still return error?

Comment: in fact, it fixed everything:) it returns correct stuff now:) and what "i" means in bind result? i saw "i", "d", "ss", is it i for integer? s for string? and if we put several we give several parameters?

Comment: yes that is correct but not for the bind_result, it is for the bind_param. you need a letter for every input variable into the query for examble: `$statement->bind_param("ss", $string1, $string2);` if you had 2 question marks in your query that needed strings.

Comment: if you need anything else just comment here since i get notified